# Difference between words for road

Tags: words, usage, word-choice

I know the following words that all mean a road of some kind:

- 道
- 町
- 街
- 路
- 道路
- 街路
- 街道
- 通り
- 通り道

What's the difference between all these words? I'd assume size would be one of them, but what is the order if this is true?

Comment: This question would be substantially improved if there was some indication that you had tried to distinguish the words from their dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several that really do not belong.

町 refers to an area, not a road. It refers to a unit of government smaller than a city (thus probably close to what you call a town.)

通り道 means "on a route to commute/school/wherever you are going to." So when you use this word, the topic of the conversation is someone and not the road itself.

街道 refers to long inter-region routes that connected different parts of Japan, the equivalent of highway system back then. Because of this origin of the term, it has a scent of history attached to it, so in modern days you can see [roads named as 街道](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%83%AD%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E8%A1%97%E9%81%93) for nobility.

The remaining words have significant overlaps between them, and while some of them have some neuances that others don't have, I'm not confident if I got the distinction right, or if such perceived neuances are mine alone or shared.

To me, it's somewhat analogus to asking the differences between Blvd/Ave/St/Rd distinctions in the U.S. Sure, Blvd sounds wider in general (just like 通り), but you can find a plenty of counter-examples.